# How to create a folder in Google Drive Sync created cloud directory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

*This question assumes you have used Google Drive Sync or at least have knowledge of what files it creates in your cloud drive*

While using [rclone](https://rclone.org) to sync a local ubuntu directory to a Google Drive (a.k.a. gdrive) *location*, I found that rclone wasn't able to (`error googleapi: Error 500: Internal Error, internalError`; the Google Cloud Platform API console revealed that the gdrive API call `drive.files.create` was failing)

By *location* I mean the root of the directory structure that the Google Drive Sync app creates on the cloud (eg. emboldened of say: **Computers/laptopName/**(syncedFolder1,syncedFolder2,...)). In the current case, the gdrive sync app (famously unavailable on Linux) was running from a separate Windows machine. It was in this location that rclone wasn't able to create a dir.

Forget rclone. Trying to manually create the folder in the web app also fails as follows.

> Working...

> Could not execute action

Why is this happening and how to achieve this - making a directory in the cloud region where gdrive sync has put all my synced folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can't. I found an explanation [here](http://error%20googleapi:%20Error%20500:%20Internal%20Error,%20internalError)

> If I am correct in my suspicion, there are a few things you have to understand:
>
> 1. Even though you may be able to create folders inside the Computers isolated containers, doing so will immediately create that folder not only in your cloud, but on that computer/device. Any changes to anything inside the Computers container will automatically be synced to the device/computer the container is linked to- just like any change on the device/computer side is also synced to the cloud.
> 2. It is not possible to create anything at the "root" level of each container in the cloud. If that were permitted then the actual preferences set in Backup & Sync would have to be magically altered to add that folder to the preferences. Thus this is not done.

So while folders inside the synced folders may be created, no new modifications may be made in the "root" dir